# Create triangular slider with HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, geometry

I'm trying to build a triangular slider similar to this:

[image]

I can figure out how to make the triangle, but the functionality such as dragging the node, bounding its location to within the triangle and determining values based on the node coordinates are beyond me right now.

If there is a plugin like this please let me know, otherwise any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For dragging the node you can use Jquery.UI draggable , with drag event returning false if point is outside the bound of the triangle (see : http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/ for algorithm). You must determine the coordinates of the vertexes of the triangle (http://jsfiddle.net/dLzWr/) .

```
//get the triangle top point
function getTopPoint(t){
    var pos = t.offset();
    //we must add the borders to the offset
    var leftBorder = parseInt(t.css("border-left-width"),10);
    var topBorder = parseInt(t.css("border-top-width"),10);
    pos.left += leftBorder;
    pos.top += topBorder;
    return pos;
}

//get the triangle bottom left point
function bottomLeftPoint(t){
    var top = getTopPoint(t);
    top.top += parseInt(t.css("border-bottom-width"),10);
    top.left -= parseInt(t.css("border-left-width"),10);
    return top;
}

//get the triangle bottom right point
function bottomRightPoint(t){
    var top = getTopPoint(t);
    top.top += parseInt(t.css("border-bottom-width"),10);
    top.left += parseInt(t.css("border-right-width"),10);
    return top;
}
```

If you take a look in the fiddle . You can determine the distance between each vertex and the current point in the draw event and use this to determine the values.